# Getting File Size - Apache Commons File Upload

Tags: servlets, file-upload, apache-commons-fileupload

I am having a webapplication built using Servlet and JSP. I have built a file upload functionality using apache commons library. I would like to restrict the user from uploading a huge file - hence have set the limit as 20 MB.

I am getting the size using `Fileitem.getSize()` method which I guess is reading the entire file to determine the size. If a user tries to upload a file of few GBs in size , then wouldn't it add a lot of overhead on the application server? Is there any better alternative for getting the file size?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you set the `sizeMax` property on `ServletFileUpload`, then the request will be rejected as soon as more than a certain amount of data is read.

Also, if you use `DiskFileItemFactory`, then you can set a threshold so that files over a certain size are streamed to local disk rather than being held in memory, which protects against large files.

Comment: Hi - Thanks! I got this error message - "The field uploadFile exceeds its maximum permitted  size of 20 characters". Is characters same as bytes? Is there a way to specify bytes?