# apache commons FileUpload - cutting off large files before whole file uploaded

Tags: java, apache, servlets, file-upload, size

Using Tomcat 6, I am using apache commons FileUpload to allow image uploads.  I can set the max files using setSizeMax and setFileSizeMax.  But it seems that an entire large file is uploaded and then checked too see if it is too big.  According to another [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8725375/getting-file-size-apache-commons-file-upload), it seems that setSizeMax should cut off the upload, but that is not the behavior I get.

To test this, I set the sizeMax and fieSizeMax very low, and uploaded a rather large file.  It took 15 secs uploading the large file, instead of cutting it off almost instantaneously.

Any idea?  Here is some code, with a simplified exception clause.

```
    FileItemFactory factory = new DiskFileItemFactory();
        ServletFileUpload upload = new ServletFileUpload(factory);
        upload.setFileSizeMax(30);
        upload.setSizeMax(28);
        List items = null;
        try {
            items = upload.parseRequest(request);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            out.println("exceeded max file size..");
            return;
        }
```

MORE INFO:  Using tomcat 6.  Setting the maxPostSize does not work for content-type: multipart/form-data.  Also, checking the request content length again requires the entire file to be uploaded.  Finally, using the steaming api of FileUpload also does not seem to work, as it again seems to require the entire file to be uploaded before the stream can be be closed; the upload will continue even if the servlet does not write the bytes to disk.  There has to be a way to prevent huge uploads using tomcat 6, as uploading images and such is a very common task for web apps.

Comment: If you can require your users to use a HTML5 compliant browser, then you can validate on the client-side. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4112575/client-checking-file-size-using-html5

Comment: @rickz - it is never a good idea to rely on client-side checking / validation to  protect the server-side.  It is too easy to subvert the checks.

Comment: @StephenC  This is not something that would run a security risk. It is just an effort to improve web app performance. If the client-side validation fails, then the server can always refuse the upload.

Comment: @rickz - I get the impression that the OP is attempting to protect the overall system performance from people who download monstrous files.  This is a denial-of-service issue, and it is is not hard to imagine someone doing it deliberately ...

Comment: @rickz - *"If the client-side validation fails, then the server can always refuse the upload."*.  On the other hand, if the (subverted) client-side skips the validation and tells the server "it is ok", then the server gets bad stuff.  People do this kind of thing all of the time, and it is foolish to pretend otherwise.

Comment: @StephenC I am not suggesting that server trust the client. Certainly both validations can be in place. In regards to the denial-of-service issue, it could be done with 1000's of small  files, so I don't see your point.

Comment: My question stems from both a user experience perspective and a server performace issue.  From a user perspective, I don't want users to waste time uploading too large of files that will be rejected at the end of the day - html5 validation will be helpful here on clients that have it.  From a server perspective, we don't want people uploading 5 GB files (as that will do nothing but take up server threads... and slow everything down)... and yes if done deliberately, it could turn into a denial-of-service issue.

Answer (score 1):

The client sends the bits whether you save them on the server or not. There is no way for the server to tell the client to stop sending bits short of forcibly closing the input stream (because of the nature of HTTP: response follows request -- they are not simultaneous). You can try that, but most application servers will drain the input stream from the client when you perform a close() so nothing will change.

If you can control the client and require the use of 100-Continue (via an Expect header), you may be able to snoop the Content-Length of the request and reject it by sending a negative reply instead of 100-Continue.

Answer (score 0):

Tomcat has a maxPostSize attribute for its HTTP Connector. See [Tomcat docs](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/config/http.html)

**Edit:** Too bad that doesn't work for multipart/form-data.  Have you considered using a signed Applet or using "Java Web Start" to manage the upload ?

Comment: As far as I can tell, request.getContentLength waits until the entire file is uploaded.  Thus, a huge file will still be uploaded completely, and then you can run that test.  That is what I get.

Comment: maxPostSize does not work for content-type multipart/form-data.  It only works for content type application/x-www-form-urlencoded.  Thus, setting the maxPostSize will have no effect on the typical case of uploading images and such via a web form.  In my tests, maxPostSize is completely ignored for cases that typically use apache commons FileUpload. see this post: [link](http://tomcat.10.n6.nabble.com/The-purpose-of-maxPostSize-td2158253.html) for a discussion.

Comment: In previous solutions, I have used an applet to control this type of scenario, but that was with an app designed for a more sophisticated community. For this section of my current project, the requirement is that users simply can upload images.  I think a signed applet would confuse users.  People develop webapps all the time to handle uploading images, so there must be a standard approach.  Or perhaps I should choose another type of server to handle uploads?  The core app woudl still be in java, but I could use a dedicated VPS with another technology for the uploads?  Any suggestions

Comment: The common choice is to use the Apache Web Server in front of Tomcat. It has the LimitRequestBody directive. I don't have experience myself. Maybe you will have to ask another question to find a Apache expert.